# replace some numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i recently did a number generator and i have an array filled with 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, because it generates numbers from 0 - 99999 and i want to make it replace only a few elements, for example if it generates 123 then i want an array to be [0, 0, 1, 2, 3], if 4467 then [0, 4, 4, 6, 7] etc
any suggestions?
thats the code i have for array:

```
let randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
let separated = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

separated = Array.from(String(randInt), Number);
```

Comment: For the mathematical way division `/` and modulo `%` will help. The other possibility is to use `randInt.toString().split("")` and then add the missing zeros at the beginning of the array

Comment: or `radInt.toString().padStart(5, 0).split('').map(Number)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it

- convert the number to a string
- pad the string with leading "0" so it is 5 characters long
- split
- map to Number
- profit

OK, the last step is optional :D

```js
// set to 123 to demonstrate
const randInt = 123;// Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
const separated = randInt.toString().padStart(5, 0).split('').map(Number);
console.log('Output:', separated);
```

Another alternative

- add 100000 to the random number, therefore you get numbers 100000-199999
- toString
- split('')
- slice(1) (to remove the leading 1)
- map to Number

note: the `split('').slice(1)` can also be `slice(1).split('')`

So really, that's two more solutions :p

```js
const randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000 + 100000);
const separated = randInt.toString().split('').slice(1).map(Number);
console.log(randInt, separated);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a full string, you can use padStart to add in leading zeros. You can split it and map it to the new array.

```js
const separated = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000).toString().padStart(5, '0').split('').map(Number);

console.log(separated);
```

You can also just do it from Array.from

```js
const nums = Array.from( {length: 5}, () => Math.floor(Math.random()*10));

console.log(nums);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it'll be helpful.

```js
 const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000); 
 console.log('randomNum is ' + randomNum);
 let finalResult = [0,0,0,0,0];
    let result = randomNum.toString().split('');
    result = result.map(num=>parseInt(num));
    const gap = finalResult.length - result.length; 
    if(gap>0){
      for(let i = 0; i< finalResult.length - gap; i++){
        finalResult[i+gap] = result[i];
      }
    }
    else
      finalResult = result;
    console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: so, 4 digit numbers up to 9998, instead of 5 up to 99999 ... and still no leading zeros

Comment: this produces `['9']` instead of `['0', '0', '0', '0', '9']` if `randomNum === 9`

Comment: @derpirscher - it only ever produces 4 digits anyway

Comment: `Math.random` is inclusive, exclusive, so it should be `Math.random() * 100000`.  Some of your `let`s should be `const`s (`randomNum`; `gap`).

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging lodash utility `padStart` and includes logic for variable size max:

```
import { padStart } from 'lodash';

const MAX = 1000;

let randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX);
const padTo = MAX.toString().length - 1

const paddedNumArr = (padStart(randInt.toString(), padTo, '0'))
      .split('')
      .map(i => parseInt(i));
```